# Can Word templates be used to store and apply Word Options?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Does a Word template store the settings selected in File > Options? For example, would it be possible to create a template that, for every document the template is attached to, will disable the "Check Spelling As You Type" option?

A small experiment with template files suggests to me that the answer to my question is "No". Is there some other way to save a profile of Word options that can be easily loaded and unloaded?

Comment: The normal.dotx file should hold these.

Comment: Is there a way for any other template to supersede the Normal template and apply different options? (I would like to distribute a template containing some utility macros along with specific options settings.)